# Documenting function closures

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

Suppose I have a function closure in my package, for example

```
f = function(x) {
    x = x
    g = function(y) x <<- y
    h = function() x
    list(g = g, h = h)
}

l = f(5)
l$g(10)
l$h()
```

What is the correct (in the official [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) sense) way of documenting this function? In particular,

1. I would like to use `roxygen2`
2. I would like to provide documentation for the functions `g` and `h`

Comment: To see how a few base R functions deal with this, see `?approxfun`, `?splinefun`, and both functions documented in `?colorRamp`. (Also, Gavin's advice seems spot on to me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to do something similar to `?family` where you document `g()` and `h()` in the `Value` section of the `.Rd` file. Then provide extended documentation about `g()` and `h()` in a bespoke `\section{foo}`, which you point to in the `Value` section entries for the two functions.

```
\value{
  Returns an object of class \code{"foo"}, a list with the
  following components:

  \item{g}{function; does foo. See Returned Functions for details.}
  \item{h}{function; does bar. See Returned Functions for details.}
}
\section{Returned Functions}{
  The returned functions do, blah blah...

  \code{g} is defined as

  \preformatted{
  g(x, y, z, ...)
  }

  Arguments are:

  \describe{
    \item{x}{foo}
    \item{y}{foo}
    \item{z}{foo}
  }
}
```

Whilst roxygen won't be able to do this from the argument `@param`, but you should be able to write this as an arbitrary roxygen section to add to the Rd file. The `Value` section can be written as standard roxygen markup, only the bespoke section would need to be entered literally.